# explanation of preg_replace function in PHP

Tags: php, regex

The `preg_replace()` function has so many possible values, like:

```
    <?php
    $patterns = array('/(19|20)(\d{2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/', '/^\s*{(\w+)}\s*=/');
    $replace = array('\3/\4/\1\2', '$\1 =');
    echo preg_replace($patterns, $replace, '{startDate} = 1999-5-27');
```

What does:

```
 \3/\4/\1\2
```

And:

```
/(19|20)(\d{2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/','/^\s*{(\w+)}\s*=/
```

mean?

Is there any information available to help understand the meanings at one place? Any help or documents would be appreciated! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The \w metacharacter is used to find a word character. + for one ore more if m not wrong

Comment: Check out [SO regex faq](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3110638), [Rexegg Cheat Sheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html), [explain regex](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl), [regex101](https://regex101.com/) (paste regex > explanation top right)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm

`\3` is the captured group 3
`\4` is the captured group 4
...an so on...

`\w` means any word character.
`\d` means any digit.
`\s` means any white space.
`+` means match the preceding pattern at least once or more.
`*` means match the preceding pattern 0 times or more.
`{n,m}` means match the preceding pattern at least `n` times to `m` times max.
`{n}` means match the preceding pattern exactly `n` times.
`(n,}` means match the preceding pattern at least n times or more.
`(...)` is a captured group.

Answer (score 3):

So, the first thing to point out, is that we have an *array of patterns* (`$patterns`), and an *array of replacements* (`$replace`). Let's take each pattern and replacement and break it down:

Pattern:

```
/(19|20)(\d{2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/
```

Replacement:

```
\3/\4/\1\2
```

This takes a date and converts it from a `YYYY-M-D` format to a `M/D/YYYY` format. Let's break down it's components:

```
/ ... / # The starting and trailing slash mark the beginning and end of the expression.
(19|20) # Matches either 19 or 20, capturing the result as \1.
        # \1 will be 19 or 20.
(\d{2}) # Matches any two digits (must be two digits), capturing the result as \2.
        # \2 will be the two digits captured here.
-       # Literal "-" character, not captured.
(\d{2}) # Either 1 or 2 digits, capturing the result as \3.
        # \3 will be the one or two digits captured here.
-       # Literal "-" character, not captured.
(\d{2}) # Either 1 or 2 digits, capturing the result as \4.
        # \4 will be the one or two digits captured here.
```

This match is replaced by `\3/\4/\1\2`, which means:

```
\3 # The two digits captured in the 3rd set of `()`s, representing the month.
/  # A literal '/'.
\4 # The two digits captured in the 4rd set of `()`s, representing the day.
/  # A literal '/'.
\1 # Either '19' or '20'; the first two digits captured (first `()`s).
\2 # The two digits captured in the 2nd set of `()`s, representing the last two digits of the year.
```

Pattern:

```
/^\s*{(\w+)}\s*=/
```

Replacement:

```
$\1 =
```

This takes a variable name encoded as `{variable}` and converts it to `$variable = <date>`. Let's break it down:

```
/ ... / # The starting and trailing slash mark the beginning and end of the expression.
^       # Matches the beginning of the string, anchoring the match.
        # If the following character isn't matched exactly at the beginning of the string, the expression won't match.
\s*     # Any whitespace character. This can include spaces, tabs, etc.
        # The '*' means "zero or more occurrences".
        # So, the whitespace is optional, but there can be any amount of it at the beginning of the line.
{       # A literal '{' character.
(\w+)   # Any 'word' character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _). This is captured in \1.
        # \1 will be the text contained between the { and }, and is the only thing "captured" in this expression.
}       # A literal '}' character.
\s*     # Any whitespace character. This can include spaces, tabs, etc.
=       # A literal '=' character.
```

This match is replaced by `$\1 =`, which means:

```
$  # A literal '$' character.
\1 # The text captured in the 1st and only set of `()`s, representing the variable name.
   # A literal space.
=  # A literal '=' character.
```

Lastly, I wanted to show you a couple of resources. The regex-format you're using is called "PCRE", or Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions. [Here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse190m/12sp/cheat-sheets/php-regex-cheat-sheet.pdf) is a quick cheat-sheet on PCRE for PHP. Over the last few years, several tools have been popping up to help you visualize, explain, and test regular expressions. One is [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) (just Google "regex tester" or "regex visualizer"). If you look [here](https://regex101.com/r/tF1gH0/1), this is an explanation of the first RegEx, and [here](https://regex101.com/r/iV4wF3/1) is an explanation of the second. There are others as well, like [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/), [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/), etc. But I find the detailed match breakdown on Regex 101 to be pretty useful.